# bring out stack view in Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0. I cannot bring out stack browsing in Chrome.
Although I have got an option for something like tilt scrolling in advanced settings but cannot find it useful any way even after enabling it. What may be the problem?

Here are some links for screenshots related to stack tabs:

[image: screen shot]

[image: screen shot]

I cannot find the button which is marked in the second screenshot, Also the browser in my tab looks a lot like the desktop one, with extremely small tabs at the top. Specifically the 'x' button used to close each tab, which is a headache but I use it a lot. It would help me if I manage to get the stack tabs feature.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome's tab switcher view is only available on phones, not tablets. This is by design, since phones don't have space for the tab bar that tablets have. The Chrome documentation [describes the differences between phones and tablets in how you work with tabs](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=2391819).

Comment: Then why do I find the 'enable tilt scrolling' option in developer tools in advanced section in settings?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't write it.